# Не выходит скомпилировать исполняемый jar с зависимостями, используя Maven

Tags: java, maven

Пытаюсь собрать проект в .jar, используя Maven. Вот мой `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dugin.rostislav</groupId>
    <artifactId>OSLoaderServer</artifactId>
    <name>OSLoaderServer</name>
    <version>1.0 alpha</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.dugin.rostislav.Main</mainClass>
                            <packageName>com.dugin.rostislav</packageName>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.25.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Но, в результате, получаю .jar'ник на 170 кб исключительно с моими скомпилированными классами и без папки lib (хотя в манифесте о этой папке говорится).

---

Что я делаю не так и как скомпилировать исполняемый .jar архив, содержащий все зависимости?

Comment: Используйте [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы всё оказалось в одном jar или Ваш jar + папка lib с другими jar-никами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующий конфиг:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
…
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>package.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
…
 </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Вместе `maven-dependency-plugin`?

Comment: Если нужно только собрать все зависимости в один jar то можно убрать и maven-jar-plugin и maven-dependency-plugin.