# В jar файл не добавляются библиотеки maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

`Речь идет не о локальных библиотеках которые надо добавить, а о самой maven библиотеке. Итак по порядку:  есть maven проект с несколькими зависимостями, запускаю instal lifecycle, создается jar, запускаю его и выдается ошибка о том, что не найдены классы из maven библиотек. Почему они н используются в jar? Что-то надо в pom дописать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в Main использую TelegramLongPoolingBot, который видимо использует интерфейс LongPoolingBot. В консоле при запуске jar такая ошибка:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.telegram.client.MyClasses.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/generics/LongPollingBot
```

Main class:

```
public class Main  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {ApiContextInitializer.init();

        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Telegram());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `классы из maven библиотек` это зависимые библиотеки, которые вы используете прямо или транзитивно в своем проекте? Если так, то тогда это дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610702/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-jar-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-maven если нет - то уточните вопрос

Comment: Непонятно о чем идет речь. Постройте пример кода и приведите точные сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: @defaultlocale, скажите если надо еще что-нибудь

Comment: @LG03 Попробуйте выложить POM.

Comment: Это дубликат вопроса: [Не выходит скомпилировать исполняемый jar с зависимостями, используя Maven](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610702/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-jar-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-maven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы зависимости из `<dependencies>` попадали в jar файл, надо добавить в ваш `pom.xml` такой плагин:

```
<project ...>
    ...

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Запаковывание зависимостей в один jar файл -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </build>
</project>
```